# Randomness of random.randint() vs uuid4

Tags: random, integer, uuid

I have used uuid4 since now in my project database (still in development) but I am now thinking about switching to random bigints for PK.

Can someone tell me, how much worse the randomness of `randint(1000000000000000, 9007199254740991)` (javascript safe) vs uuid4 is?

I bet, I am using the term randomness wrong here. What I want to achieve is, that I do not have continous but of course unique ids in my DB, thats why I used uuid until now. But because I ran into a lot of troubles I would like to switch to integers now and would like to know how much "more random" uuid would have been

Answer (score 0):

Just eyeballing it, 9007199254740991 looks like about 55 bits; UUIDv4 has 122 random bits, which means it has about 2^67 times more randomness. You lose one bit or so by cutting off the low end of the range, which is easy to fix, but it doesn't really matter when the difference is already that stark.